# Java JTextField wont show

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm creating some GUI and I have made this JDialog where I'm trying to create a template for name, phone No., and age.
My problem is that when you push the button you call this method:

```
public void createKunde(){
        JDialog addDialog = new JDialog(frame);
        JPanel addContentPane =(JPanel) addDialog.getContentPane();
        addContentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(12,12,12,12));

        addContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(6,6));

        addDialog.setTitle("Opret Kunde");
        addDialog.setSize(800, 400);
        addDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        addDialog.setModal(true);
        addDialog.setVisible(true);

        JPanel addContent = new JPanel();
        addContent.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));

        JTextField addName = new JTextField(50);
        addContent.add(addName);

        JTextField addAge = new JTextField(50);
        addContent.add(addAge);

        JTextField addPhone = new JTextField(50);
        addContent.add(addPhone);


        addContentPane.add(addContent, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addDialog.add(addContentPane);
    }
```

I Just can't get the TextFields to be shown in my JDialog. I can't see where the problem should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your JDialog visible, add this at the end and remove it from the top:

```
addDialog.setVisible(true);
```

As far as i remember java swing, you can't make first something visible and the build it.

Here you have an other exmaple:

```
private void showSimpleDialog() {
    final JDialog d = new JDialog(this, "Run", true);
    d.setSize(200, 150);
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Pagination Swing Demo", JLabel.CENTER);
    d.getContentPane( ).setLayout(new BorderLayout( ));
    d.getContentPane( ).add(l, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JButton b = new JButton("Run");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener( ) {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
          createFrame();
          d.setVisible(false);
          d.dispose( );
         }
      });
    JPanel p = new JPanel( );     // Flow layout will center button.
    p.add(b);
    d.getContentPane( ).add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    d.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    d.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example is helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

your code is trying to add same parent to container itself ie jdailog to jdsilog itself

and your addDialog is not set as visible after adding components

so better make it visible at the end

here is your complete modified working program

```
package com.kb.gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class JdialogEx1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createKunde();
    }

    public static void createKunde(){
        Frame frame = new JFrame();
        JDialog addDialog = new JDialog(frame);
        JPanel addContentPane =(JPanel) addDialog.getContentPane();
        addContentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(12,12,12,12));

        addContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(6,6));

        addDialog.setTitle("Opret Kunde");
        addDialog.setSize(800, 400);
        addDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        addDialog.setModal(true);


        JPanel addContent = new JPanel();
        addContent.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));

        JTextField addName = new JTextField(50);
        addContent.add(addName);

        JTextField addAge = new JTextField(50);
        addContent.add(addAge);

        JTextField addPhone = new JTextField(50);
        addContent.add(addPhone);

       addContentPane.add(addContent, BorderLayout.WEST);
       addDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```